# Games won’t load in MAME 2003 (Retropie)

Tags: retropie

I am running the latest version of Retropie with Libretro MAME 2003. It’s my understanding that this version uses 0.78 roms. I have a set, but when I attempt to play games on the Pi, only some of them will run. Others will go to a black screen as though the game is loading, but then will return to the game list.

I’ve googled quite a bit but can’t figure out what’s going wrong here. Has anyone else encountered this? Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I think I figured it out. I was running a rebuild in clrmamepro when it wasn’t necessary.